# how to convert datetime to a particular format

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private void buildGrid()
{
    this.currentActivities = new XSPIncidentActivityModel.XSPIncidentActivityEntities(BuildEntityConnectionString("XSMDSN")).XSP_IncidentActivity.Where(ia => ia.IncidentID == this.IncidentID).OrderBy(ia=>ia.CompletionDate).ToList();

    foreach (XSPIncidentActivityModel.XSP_IncidentActivity act in this.currentActivities)
    {
        act.CompletionDate.AddHours(this.TimeZoneOffset); 


        if (act.CompletionDate.IsDaylightSavingTime())
        {
act.CompletionDate.AddHours(-1).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
        }
    }

    CommonGrid1.BindDataSource(this.currentActivities);
}
```

I have to conert the datetime object to a particular format i.e, currentl;y it displays 9/14/2009 12:20:30 PM

i have to display in this manner 9/14/2009 12:20 PM

by converting it to string string s = String.Format("{0:g}", act.CompletionDate.AddHours(this.TimeZoneOffset));  i can display date time without seconds.

But since the data is coming from sql server i have to dislay the datetime object (act.CompletionDate) in that particular format

i tried this but it isnot working
string[] expectedFormats = {"G", "g", "f" ,"F"};
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
act.CompletionDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, expectedFormats, culture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);

Answer (score 2):

Some examples that may help

```
  public static string Change_to_date_yymmdd(DateTime dt)
    {
        //string strTest = stringTest();
        string format = "yyMMdd";
        string date = dt.ToString(format, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
        return date;
    }

    public static string Change_to_time_24hr60min60sec60ms(DateTime dt)
    {
        string format = "HHmmssff";
        string time = dt.ToString(format, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
        return time;

    }
    public static string Change_to_rangevalidator(DateTime dt)
    {
        //string strTest = stringTest();
        string format = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss";
        string date = dt.ToString(format, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
        return date;
    }
```

Comment: act.completiondate is a datetime object and i have to display it as a datetime object withot converting it to string

Comment: I fail to see how this can help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming act.CompletionDate is of type System.DateTime, your code lines which call act.CompletionDate.AddHours are doing nothing, because the AddHours method does not change the instance on which it is invoked. Instead a new DateTime is returned which has the hours added. You can fix this by doing something like:-

```
act.CompletionDate = act.CompletionDate.AddHours(-1)
```

Likewise, the calls to ToString also achieve nothing since the ToString method does nothing to the instance on which it is invoked. It returns a new string object, generated based on the value of the DateTime.

Instead, in order to fix your formatting problem, try setting the ItemStyle.DataFormatString for the column in the GridView which displays the date. For an example of how to do this, have a look at the MSDN article [GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Formatting the GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx).

Comment: can you please tell me how to set the relevant formatting property on column of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the culture format for ALL dates (and other locale specific output) then you can do this in the web.config for your entire application:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt");
// prints in this format 9/14/2009 12:20 PM
```